# Make \item inside enumerate vertically aligned with a math block?

Tags: math-mode, positioning, enumerate

I am trying to use the `align*` environment (but I guess it also applies the math block `$$...$$`) inside the `enumerate` environment. It seems to have an extra line above my math block:

[image: What I currently have]

Is there a way to remove this line? I could understand that the block somehow created a new paragraph. Could I create a container that contains both the counter and the math block, and make the counter float at the top-left at the container?

I tried to make a `figure[t]` containing my `align*`, but the whole “figure” flies to the top of the whole page. Inline math `$...$` doesn’t work for me, neither, because I don’t like the counter to be centered—not sure if this is a typography standard, but I don’t like it.

A minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \begin{align*}
            a + b &= a + b \\
            a - b &= 0
          \end{align*}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Don't use `$$...$$` Use `\[...\]` instead

Comment: Could you post a minimal (non-)working example? It will be easier to help you.

Comment: `\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}` before `\[ ...\]` helps (a little bit)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sorry for the confusion, I actually used `align*`.

Comment: @Bernard Sorry, I am gonna add it quickly.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by your disinterest in using inline math `$...$`. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Werner If I use `align*`/`aligned` it means that the math content would span multiple lines. If I use an inline math block, the counter will be put vertically center. This is misleading for readers, since it would be hard for them to realize that the old “section” has ended and a new one has started.

Comment: @Werner I know how to the problem now, thank you.

Comment: @MinshengLiu: What is misleading is the fact that your minimal example doesn't replicate your problem when using inline math...

Comment: @Werner I got some complicated indentation in my original source code, so I don’t want mess them up here. You are right. Sorry about this.

Comment: Your MWE doesn't reproduce image which you show in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use an `align*` environment; instead, use an `aligned` environment, with a `[t]` (for "top") location specifier, inside a pair of `$` math-mode delimiters. The first item below shows the equation flush-left, and the second item shows the equation centered.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item $\begin{aligned}[t]
            a + b &= a + b \\
            a - b &= 0
          \end{aligned}$ 
    \item \hfil $\begin{aligned}[t]
            a + b &= a + b \\
            a - b &= 0
          \end{aligned}$ \hfill
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, I didn’t know/notice the `[t]` option. Thank you.